# Is there a method in Ruby that does the opposite of find?

Tags: ruby, arrays, api, enumerable

```
a, b, c = 0, 1, 2
[a, b, c].find(&:zero?) # => 0
```

Is there any method that finds the first element for which the block returns false?

```
[a, b, c].the_method(&:zero?) # => 1
```

In other words, it would behave the same way as:

```
[a, b, c].reject(&:zero?).first
```

Comment: `reject(...).first` seems like what you're after -- what's wrong with that?

Comment: what about using _Proc_ ?  `[a, b, c].find{|i| i != 0 }`

Comment: @Joe the problem with that is you loop through the entire collection and create a full array of all matching values, and then throw them all out. The beauty of `find` is that it stops iterating as soon as it find the first matching value.

Comment: In general no, but here: `[1,2,3].find(&:nonzero?) # => 1` :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There [is not](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html), but you could create one either the clean-ish way:

```
a = [0,2,1,0,3]

module Enumerable
  def first_not(&block)
    find{ |x| !block[x] }
  end
end

p a.first_not(&:zero?)
#=> 2
```

...or the horribly-amusing hack way:

```
class Proc
  def !
    proc{ |o,*a| !self[o,*a] }
  end
end

p a.find(&!(:zero?.to_proc))
#=> 2
```

...or the terse-but-terribly-dangerous way:

```
class Symbol
  def !
    proc{ |o,*a| !o.send(self,*a) }
  end
end

p a.find(&!:zero?)
#=> 2
```

But I'd advocate just skipping the tricky `Symbol#to_proc` usage and saying what you want:

```
p a.find{ |i| !i.zero? }
#=> 2
```

Comment: hack ways for the win! =)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Ruby 2.0, you may be able to do `lazy.reject(&:zero?).first` without the performance penalty of going through the full array.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell there is not a standard method to do this (given that find_all and reject reference each other, but find does not reference anything).  If you need it frequently (especially if the reject is too slow) you can write your own

```
module Enumerable

  def first_reject(&block)
    find {|a| not (block.call(a)) }
  end

end
```

Comment: I do, however, agree with Phrogz that just writing out the function is usually best.